# Input Masking of Controls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to create input controls which should be masked with formats like date, phone etc. in mvc4 application. Please let me know how to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display watermark instead of value in textbox in ASP.Net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022351/how-to-display-watermark-instead-of-value-in-textbox-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: use `PlaceHolder` in HTML. For example - `@Html.TextBox("Name", "Value", new { placeholder = "Enter name" })`